# First millennium BC Egyptian rudder systems

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Hello I am researching first millennium BC Nile freighter rudders. They sailed upstream and came  back down with the current. The Greek writer Herodotus tells us that going downstream they were towed by a raft  and towed a stone behind, no doubt to provide steeridge way. Most had twin quarter rudders but a recent excavation had two closely spaced holes in the keel.  Amongst other possibilities they may have been used for a pair of rudders with blades on one side only with one facing forward and the other facing aft.

In use they may have acted as a reversable rudder and skeg. The rearward blade was lashed amidships when going downstream with the ship presenting her stern to the current and the forward rudder would be used. When sailing upstream the forward rudder would be lashed and the rearward one used. Overall length of the rudders is unknown as is the profile. Do you think the hydrodynamics could act to make it function as a single foil given that the blades were flat.  The  vessel was around 26M in length

Q

Comment: Some drawings would be nice. Why would they need to be towed downstream? Surely steering the towing raft would be far more difficult? How would a rudder help when moving at the same speed as the water (zero relative velocity)?

Comment: The raft would not be affected by the wind to the same extent as the ship and could be used to carry extra cargo. It would sit low in the water and in the grip of the current. Herodotus does not say that the raft had a rudder but it may have. The ship followed the raft and towed the stone or stones so as to slow the whole rig down to below the speed of the current. This gave steeridge way. Just to be clear, when going downstream against the wind the order would be raft first followed by ship and then stone. Hope this helps. I will have to find out how to add drawings.

Comment: That's interesting. I hadn't considered wind in my comment. I presume that the stones were bottom dragging and so the boats ran more slowly than the river thus generating a velocity difference. There's an image upload button on the editor toolbar. Give each a caption and a citation if it's not your own artwork.

Comment: So just edited and still no images...